# Manually add hours to the log4j timestamp?

Tags: java, log4j, dst

In my country we are not using the time setting **Adjust for daylight saving time automatically**.
It is disabled on windows settings.
For example: `11 AM here, log4j shows 10AM.`
I read that I can upgrade JDK but I was wondering that can I add `+1` for hour
somewhere in `log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern =%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %m%n` here to adjust the hour for my setting.
Otherwise, I will just append the timestamp manually from my java class.

Answer (score 1):

What version of log4j u are using?  Its a know issue with DST in the **FixedDateFormat** class that **Log4j2** uses for the predefined date formats.
ref: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1849

Now its fixed after Log4j 2.8.2 release